# How to translate an SQL to TypeORM query builder?

Tags: sql, typescript, sql-order-by, ascii, typeorm

How would I convert the code below to TypeORM querybuilder?

```
SELECT * FROM "user"

  ORDER BY (CASE 

  WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(display_name,1)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN 3

  WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(display_name,1)) < 128 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END), display_name;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly run sql query in typeorm module in your project

first of all import in controller

```
import {  getManager } from "typeorm";
```

```
  const entityManager = getManager();

 locationQuery = await entityManager.query(`SELECT * FROM "user"

  ORDER BY (CASE 

  WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(display_name,1)) BETWEEN 48 AND 57 THEN 3

  WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(display_name,1)) < 128 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END), display_name;`);
```